# Remove the white space and new line from the CSV file using shell script and save it in the same or different file

Tags: mysql, shell, csv, sed

I am importing a CSV file and save the details in the file into the database using the shell script (.sh file )

In the CSV file, one column contains multiple image URL and that is separated by the '|'. But the details are having the white spaces and the line breaks. I need to remove the same and upload the details in the database without the line break.

Values in the column are like below,

```
http:///url/385924/pictures/THIRDPARTY|http://url/385924/pict
ures/THIRDPARTY|http://url/385924/pictures/b2af65b2-4d12-45dd-87a8- 
0ebc0c32c8e8-THIRDPARTY|http://url/THIRDPARTY|http://url.windo
ws.net/pictures/85eb568b-7908-49b2-9d91-4f762077323b- 
THIRDPARTY|http://url/vehicles/385924/THIRDPARTY
```

I need it without white space and new line like

```
http:///url/385924/pictures/THIRDPARTY|http://url/385924/pictures/THIRDPARTY|http://url/385924/pictures/2af65b2-4d12-45dd-87a8-0ebc0c32c8e8-THIRDPARTY|http://url/THIRDPARTY|http://url.windows.net/pictures/85eb568b-7908-49b2-9d91-4f762077323b-THIRDPARTY|http://url/vehicles/385924/THIRDPARTY
```

My code is given below,

```
FILE1="/filepath/file.csv
File2 = "/filepath/newfile.csv"
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' $FILE1 > '/filepath to new file/newfile.csv'
FILE2="/filepath to new file/newfile.csv'"

mysql -u username -ppassword database name  -Bse "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$FILE2"' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@ignore ,id,imagename,@ignore ,@ignore  ,@ignore ,@ignore ,@ignore ,@ignore ,@ignore);"
```

While using only the `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' $FILE1`, in the terminal I am getting the data in the CSV file without the spaces and new line. If I have replaced `':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'` with `':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/---/g'` it is also reflecting in the terminal. The results are not saving in the current CSV file or while saving in a new CSV file.

How to do the sed actions and then save it in the same CSV file or in a new CSV file, and use that in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to isolate you problem? I mean, it seems `sed` is working fine for you, you get the desired output, but you just can't put that output into a file successfully, is that right? Then, proofread your script or run shellchek on it. It has many errors.

Comment: Add this to your sed: `;s/ //g`

Comment: What is that `File2 = "/filepath/newfile.csv"`? Those spaces are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this?

```
sed -z 's/ *\n//g' yourfile
```

The `-z` options allows you to edit the file as it was a single line.

Comment: Hi Enrico, I want to save the trimmed values in the same file or in a new file and save the details into the database.

Comment: @VarunPV, I don't understand. Please clarify all that needs to be clarified in your question, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).